# Python, regex: find and replace all instances of "yyyy" except when in front of a period

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a numeric string and replace it. For example, let's say "1998", and replace it with "1999" in all of the files in the current directory. However, I do not want to conduct this replacement for strings that look like "1998." (i.e. `1998.csv`, `1998.png`, `1998.xlsx`, etc.). How do I do this? I looked up the documentation for `replace()` and it doesn't have options for regular expressions.

```
inputDir = "."
outputDir = "./test"
find = "1998"
replace = "1999" 

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(inputDir)): 
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(filepath) as f:
            s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(find, replace) # second, update all years
```

Comment: Perhaps use `re.sub` with the pattern `(?<!\S)1998(?!\S)` and replace with 1999

Comment: why do you need RE for this? you can simply iterate over all the file names ``` if "1998" in fileName```....

Comment: @VaibhavSharma I'm not changing the file names. I'm changing text within the files.

Comment: @Thefourthbird could you help rewrite my `for` loops in a way that integrates your solution? I'm not exactly sure how to do the regex on the open text file, `s`

Comment: You could see how it works with re.sub in this demo https://ideone.com/H7v4vG You might try `s = re.sub(r"(?<!\S)1998(?!\S)", "1999", s)`

Comment: @user2205916 Did that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me! you need to use (?<=...), check [python re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
>>> import re
>>> a='Sample 1998 test with 1998.txt file'
>>> re.sub('(?<!\S)1998(?!\S)', '1999', a)
'Sample 1999 test with 1998.txt file'
```

Comment: Can you please explain the regex: `?<!\S`?

Answer (score 0):

You could find 1998 and use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to assert what comes directly before `(?<!\S)` and after `(?!\S)` is not a `\S` non whitespace char.

In the replacement use 1999

```
(?<!\S)1998(?!\S)
```

The line in your code might look like:

```
s = re.sub(r"(?<!\S)1998(?!\S)", "1999", s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5lsl5G/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/H7v4vG)

An example

```
import re
regex = r"(?<!\S)1998(?!\S)"
test_str = ("this is 1998\n"
    "1998.csv 1998.png, 1998.xlsx")

result = re.sub(regex, "1999", test_str)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Result

```
this is 1999
1998.csv 1998.png, 1998.xlsx 1999
```

Another option if what follows can not be a dot only is to use a negative lookahead and start 1998 with a word boundary:

```
\b1998(?!\.)
```